# django_filter Django Rest Framework (DRF) handling query_params get vs getlist

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-filter

Is it correct that filtering by a list of values remains overly complicated in django_filter and, by extention, the Django Rest Framework (DRF) or am I missing something simple?

Specifically, Must we specify a-priori the parameters that should be handled with 'getlist' rather than with 'get' when we process a multi-value parameter submitted via URL like below:

http://example.com?country=US&country=CN

Now, when we process this request,

*request.query_params.get('country')* as well as  *request.query_params['country']* will erroneously return 'CN' while *request.query_params.getlist('country')* will return ['US','CN'], which is what we wish in this example.

So my current logic dictates that I have to specify in advance which parameters may have multiple values specified, as I don't know of an internal method that handles this transparently:

So to handle this I currently do something like this (skipping all the actual request processing, filtering, etc. for the sake of simplicity):

```
class CountryFilter(filters.FilterSet):
     """ placeholder: this is a separate question as to why I can't get any of these to work as desired. """
     #country = filters.CharFilter(method='filter_country')
     #country = filters.CharFilter(name='country', lookup_expr='in')
     #country = filters.MultipleChoiceFilter()

class CountryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Viewset to work with countries by ISO code"""

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """do something based on a request for one or more countries
        such as http://example.com?country=CA&country=CN&country=BR
        """
        query_params = request.query_params
        filter0 = CountryFilter(query_params, queryset=Country.objects.all())       

        # if filter0 worked, we'd be done and wouldn't need below
        # but it doesn't

        query_dict = {}
        params_to_list = ['country', 'another_param']
        for k in query_params.keys():
            if k in params_to_list:
                query_dict[k] = query_params.getlist(k)
            else:
                query_dict[k] = query_params.get(k)

        # use the newly counstructed query_dict rather than query_params
        filter1 = CountryFilter(query_dict, queryset=Country.objects.all())

        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        return HttpResponse('ok')
```

In theory, filter1 should give me the desired results while filter0 will not.

Code based on this works in my production environment but has some other effects like turning the valid list back into a string. I don't want to drift into that question here, just wondering if this is what people do or not?

Answer (score 2):

> Specifically, Must we specify a-priori the parameters that should be handled with 'getlist' rather than with 'get' when we process a multi-value parameter submitted via URL like below:

This is not necessary. `Filter` instances construct a form field that in turn performs the query param validation. These fields are standard Django form fields, and its *widget* will determine whether or not to use `.getlist()` or `.get()` when extracting values from the query dict. You do not need to preprocess the query dict.

In your example, filter0 and filter1 should actually behave identically, since `QueryDict('a=1&a=2')` is functionally equivalent to `dict(a=['1', '2'])` for `SelectMultiple`  widgets. Its [`.value_from_datadict()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11/django/forms/widgets.py#L726-L731) will call `.getlist()` on the former and `.get()` on the latter - both will return a list of values.

---

As to solving your issue of filtering by multiple values, you have two options.

1. Use a `MultipleChoiceFilter` ([docs](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/develop/ref/filters.html#choicefilter))
2. Use a CSV-based filter ([docs](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/develop/ref/filters.html#baseinfilter))

Multiple choice filters render a select multiple widget and expects a querystring like `?a=1&a=b`. You attempted this above, however you omitted `choices`. Without choices, the html select will be rendered without options, and validation will subsequently fail (since it uses those same options to validate input). Alternatively, you can use [`ModelMultipleChoiceFilter`](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/develop/ref/filters.html#modelmultiplechoicefilter), which requires a `queryset` to construct its choices from. Note that the queryset/choice handling is builtin behavior of the underlying form field, and isn't specific to django-filter.

For the latter option, there are more details in the docs linked above, but it's worth mentioning that it renders a text input and expects a querystring like `?a=1,2` instead of `?a=1&a=2`.